# Angular js bootstrap ui modal timeout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to open a bootstrap modal with the $timeout function, however the modal keeps opening as timeout fires more than once. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

```
SessionModalInstCtrl = ($scope, $modal, $timeout) ->
   $timeout (->
     $modal.open(
       templateUrl: 'session-timeout.html'
       controller: 'MmmSessionModalInstCtrl')
   ), 1000
```

Heres what my view looks like

```
%div{'data-ng-controller' => 'SessionModalInstCtrl'}
   %script{id: "session-timeout.html", type: "text/ng-template"}
    // modal content
```

Comment: What is causing `$timeout` to fire more than once?. It normally should only fire once. Find what is causing the multiple firings (likely you are instantiating the `SessionModalInstCtrl` multiple times somewhere) and you will find the cause of the modal opening multiple times.

Comment: thanks figured it out

Comment: i had defined controller in $modal.open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it. Controller can't be defined in `open`.

```
  $modal.open(
    templateUrl: 'session-timeout.html')
```